# Webpacker requires Node.js >= v6.4 and you are using v5.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, configuration, installation, webpacker

I'm trying to install rails webpacker with the command:

rails webpacker:install

but i got the error: Webpacker requires Node.js >= v6.4 and you are using v5.4.0

But typing **nodejs --version** returns: **v8.4.0**

Comment: What do you get with `node --version` (without js)

Comment: I always get v8.4.0

Comment: What OS are you on? Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04. After 1h i just got my answer.. **sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node** do the trick. now it works.

Comment: Awesome! Better answer your own question then :)

Answer (score 1):

After 1h i just got my answer. The following command will do the trick:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Now it works