# Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.30

Tags: node.js, node-modules, webpacker

I'm trying to push a Rails 5 app to Heroku but my build is failing due to the error `Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.30`.

Running `node -v` gives `v9.3.0`

**Gem**

`gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.2'`

Doesn't look like it's linking to any version:

```
Simons-MBP:my_app Simon$ npm outdated
Package                Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@rails/webpacker       MISSING   3.2.0   3.2.0
```

And yet:

```
Simons-MBP:my_app Simon$ node -v
v9.3.0
```

What am I missing?  Where else can I check?

Comment: You probably have more than one version of node installed and gem or webpacker is finding the wrong version.  Search your entire hard drive for all versions of node and remove the ones that aren't the latest version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpacker requires Node.js >= v6.4 and you are using v5.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844058/webpacker-requires-node-js-v6-4-and-you-are-using-v5-4-0)

Comment: Are you using nvm? I had the same issue with that. Had to uninstall nvm and install node manually.

Comment: What does `nodejs - v` give you?

Comment: @AyushGupta `Simons-MBP:my_app Simon$ nodejs -v
-bash: nodejs: command not found`